# Error: file `vendigram.sty` not found. \usepackage

Tags: packages, venn-diagrams

I am using TeXstudio and I have the problem that nothing seems to work, after I add the package `\usepackage{venndiagram}`.

It shows me: Error: file `vendigram.sty` not found. \usepackage 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Compile: PDFLaTeX BibTeX PDFLaTeX PDFLaTeX
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\documentclass[10pt,paper=a4,abstracton]{scrartcl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%PACKAGES%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}



\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={:~}}
\setcitestyle{chicago}

\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{vowel}

\usepackage[noenc,safe]{tipa}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{gb4e}
```

Comment: The error seems to say about `vendigram.sty`, which points to a typo in your file.

Comment: The quoted error message complains about `vendigram` being not found while th package is actually called `venndigram` (which you actually used in your document). Are you sure the shown preamble really produces the quoted error message?

Comment: @leandriis/ You have a typo: it should be  `venndiagram` (albeit  `digram` is perfect for the two`n`s).